# When print ASCII 0x07 character on console in .NET this causes system beep

Tags: .net, console, ascii, beep

I write such code in VB.NET:

```
Console.WriteLine(ChrW(7))
```

And this is causes the system beep. What is this? And how to off this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is this?

The `BEL` character/code: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character

> And how to off this behavior?

Don't send character 7 to the console when you don't want it to beep.

Comment: So simple)) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you never want beeps from the console, stop or disable the beep service.

For example,

```
net stop beep
```

in an Administrative command prompt.

Comment: Thank you! I'll check this, maybe it's a solution.